# How to use python venv from electron & node js

Tags: python, node.js, electron, dependencies, python-venv

i've just finished my electron js, node js, python app and it works very well, but i have still one issue, when i package my app and that i open it, python shell return no module named PIL however the package is installed in my virtual environment.
I think i don't use properly the venv.
I put the code on github i didn't upload the whole directory yet but you have main files (i retired the py file from the venv where i have installed numpy and pillow).
Here the url: https://github.com/Xam-Mlr/StegnHide
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried activating the venv before running the app ?

Comment: Can you explain ?